# Why can't I create a boto3 resource in a 2nd thread?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

When I call this code the first time from my main thread ddb is assigned the dynamodb resource.  However, when I call this a 2nd time from another thread the session.resource calls blocks or hangs.  Any idea how to fix?

```
session = boto3.session.Session()
ddb = session.resource('dynamodb', "us-west-1", aws_access_key_id="mykey", aws_secret_access_key="mysecretkey")
```

same thing happens if I try this code:

```
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    s3 = session.resource('s3')
```

On the 2nd call, session.resource blocks or hangs.

Comment: It appears that boto3 hangs when I try session.resource in the 2nd thread, regardless if I create it in the 1st (main) thread.  its within a flask process if that matters.

Comment: stranger yet, I was going to debug this using pycharm, but it works perfectly in pycharm but not executing from a terminal window